# Catch SQL raise error in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, raiserror

I generate the raise error in SQL procedure:

**`RAISERROR('Already exist',-10,-10)`**

but I can not catch it using the following code in C#

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    bResult = false;                   
    if (ex.Errors[0].Number == -10)
    {
        CommonTools.vAddToLog("bInsertNewUser", "ManageUsers", ex.Message);
        if ((savePoint != null))
            savePoint.Rollback();
    }
}
```

How can I catch the raised error in C# ?

Comment: And what is your exact problem? Doesn't the `try-catch` work?

Comment: Running in the debugger, are you even getting an exception that ends up in the catch clause, and if so, what's in `ex.Errors[0].Number`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

RAISERRORs with a SEVERITY value under or equal to 10 are not caught on the C# side because I suppose they are considered just warnings as you can see from the
list at [Database Engine Error Severities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities).

SEVERITY values between 11 and 16 are errors that can be corrected by the user, so, for example, you can try with:

```
RAISERROR('Already exist',16,1)
```

Otherwise, you could choose another error code from the list above or, if you really need it, prepare your own custom error message using [sp_addmessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addmessage-transact-sql).

Answer (score 11):

Your if statement is where things fail. Assuming that the first error in the collection is indeed the one you are looking for (it might not be).

[`SqlError.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not the value that you set in `RAISERROR`.

Use [`SqlError.Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.class%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retrieve the severity of the error, or [`SqlError.State`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.state%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check the state (both are -10 in your example. so difficult to tell which out you mean):

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    bResult = false;                   
    if (ex.Errors[0].Class == -10)
    {
        CommonTools.vAddToLog("bInsertNewUser", "ManageUsers", ex.Message);
        if ((savePoint != null))
            savePoint.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an error code within 11-16, or just use 16 for a "general" case.

```
RAISERROR('Already exists',16,1)
```

Why? Here's my summary of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-error-severities?view=sql-server-2017:

SQL RAISERROR -> C#:

- 0-10 = fyi*
- 11-16 = you can fix it**
- 17-19 = get admin help
- 20-24 = definitely get admin help***

*(don't throw anything) ┬──┬

**(16 = general)

***(fatal error)