# Catch RAISERROR from SQL Server in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, exception, raiseerror

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that throws an error whenever a condition is hit. In order to catch this error and display it to the user, I use

```
try 
{
   //code
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
   return BadRequest(e.Message);
}
```

This catches most of the cases but on the other hand, this procedure has some `print` messages that also get caught by this `Exception`. Is there a way to catch the exception thrown only from `RAISERROR` and ignore this `print` message from SQL Server?

Comment: `PRINT` never produces exceptions. What is probably happening is that, when a message with a high severity is raised, the earlier lower-severity `PRINT` messages get rolled into the error. You should be able to distinguish and filter these by catching `SqlException` specifically and using the `Errors` property. Conceivably, you might also be able to pre-emptively filter them by hooking up an event handler to `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` (disclaimer: not tested, and this may not do anything due to buffering).

Comment: `print` messages from SQL Server shouldn't be generating exceptions, not if you're just using the ADO.Net objects (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc). So if you're getting exceptions, it's either extra code working with those objects turning the messages into exceptions, or it's some other library/stack being used that does this. None of which we can see in `//code`.

Comment: Look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22126876/5967360

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to get the SQL Server "PRINT" value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749826/need-to-get-the-sql-server-print-value-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you actually using RAISERROR to "print" messages immediately?

Answer (score 3):

All info and error messages generated during command execution are buffered and available when a [SqlException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors) is caught. The Message property includes the text of all info messages (print statements and errors with a severity of less than 11) and the warnings/errors that caused the exception.

To ignore info messages, use the SqlException Errors collection and process only those with severity (SqlError.Class property) of 11 or higher:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(var error in e.Errors)
   {
       if(error.Class > 10) sb.AppendLine(error.message);
   }
   return BadRequest(sb.ToString());
}
```