# SqlException logs RAISEERROR and PRINT statements from .NET

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, procedure, sqlexception

I have a procedure which does some logic and raises an error if a condition has been fulfilled. This procedure is made in SQL Server and is called from .NET Core. This is the part where the `RAISEERROR` is written.

```
IF @tmp_cnt < @ent_cnt  
 BEGIN  
  DECLARE @msg AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('Not all of the selected entities are eligible for change. Will be changed for ',  
           CAST(@tmp_cnt AS NVARCHAR(50)), ' out of the selected ', CAST(@ent_cnt AS NVARCHAR(50)), ' entities.')  
  RAISERROR(@msg, 15, 1)  
 END  
  
 print 'Set FII.IsCurrent = 0'  
 UPDATE fii
```

The error should be raised but the procedure should keep doing its stuff i.e. this `print` statement should print out. However, when I catch the error in .NET, I get this `print` value as well. How do I handle it on a .NET side? This is the way I do it

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   return BadRequest(e.Message);
}
```

Said so, when I reach this `catch` block, the error I get is `Not all of the selected entities are ligible for change... \r\nSet FII.IsCurrent = 0`. What is noticeable here is that this `SqlException` logs both the `RAISEERROR` and `print` but my goal is to only get the value from `RAISEERROR`. How could I do this?

Comment: So is it Ado.net or using any ORM?

Comment: Not that experienced with .NET yet but I use entity framework, so I believe it's orm

Comment: Possible dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214619/catch-raiserror-from-sql-server-in-net/70215479#70215479).

Comment: Yes, most likely! This worked, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch RAISERROR from SQL Server in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214619/catch-raiserror-from-sql-server-in-net) You can accept this as a duplicate and it will close the question for you